# How to circle an area for emphasis in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

The intent here is to emphasize a portion of a slide. It could be an arbitrary portion of an architectural diagram or a certain area of an image as examples.

This is unrelated to adding a circle "shape" from the Insert|Shape|circle..

I will create a separate textbox with the comments I have and attach it to the circled area.

How to do this?